# Error When Installing Magento - Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch

Tags: php, magento, installation, xampp, magento2

I'm installing Magento 2 for the first time following this tutorial https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-install-magento-2-using-composer. XAMPP is installed (with Apache and MySQL running), the database is setup on PHPMyAdmin, but when I try to run **php bin/magento setup:install** (step 23 in the tutorial) I get the error: `Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download Elastic Search first on your system -

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-7-6-0

After Downloading follow this step -

- Extract the .zip file
- Open Terminal or command prompt and go to the extracted path
- run command .\bin\elasticsearch.bat

if this does not work just go to the extracted folder and opened the elasticsearch.bat file inside the bin folder.

and the install Magento with **setup: install** command.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Please run this Command in Terminal

1. **sudo service elasticsearch start**
2. And after run that command again run **php bin/magento setup:install**

Hope Your issue will be solve.
Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).